# Realm backed RecyclerView Showing Null Data

Tags: android, realm, dagger-2

I am trying to implement delete item in a Realm backed ReceyclerView. When a user selects an Item in the RecyclerView, I take the user to another Activity where they are given an option to delete the selected item. If user deletes the item I want them to go back to the previous Activity.

However when they come back the previous Activity, the deleted item is still showing even though it is now null. I have used both native RecyclerView and [RealmRecyclerView](https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview) with no success.

In MainActivity I start the detail Activity like this

```
public void showNoteDetailUi(int noteId) {
        Intent intent =  new Intent(this, NoteDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And on the detail Activity, I delete the item like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
         case R.id.action_delete:
            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            Note note = getNote(id);
            note.removeFromRealm();
            mRealm.commitTransaction();
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I defined my CRUD methods in seperate file that I call NoteManager, here are some of the content of this NoteManager which shows how I get the list of Items from Realm.

```
public class NoteRealmManager implements NotesContract.Service{
    private Realm mRealm;

    public NoteRealmManager(Context context){
        mRealm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        Note note = getNote(id);
        note.removeFromRealm();
        mRealm.commitTransaction();

    }

    @Override
    public RealmResults<Note> getAllNotes() {
        mRealm.refresh();
        RealmResults<Note> noteModels =
                mRealm.where(Note.class).findAll();
        return noteModels;
    }
}
```

And I am injecting that class to every Activity like this

```
@Module
public class PersistenceModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    public NotesContract.Service providesNoteManager(Context context){
        return new NoteRealmManager(context);
    }
}
```

And

```
 @Inject NotesContract.Service mNoteManager
```

I have tried to refresh the list, any idea how I can make Realm not show null data in a RecyclerView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a simple fix, the RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter has an overloaded constructor that allows you to set automaticUpdate to either true or false, I set this to true and it now works.

```
noteAdapter = new NoteRealmAdapter(getBaseContext(), notes,true, false, null);
    realmRecyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
```